# SharePoint 2013 Search: CreatedBy empty

Tags: search, sharepoint

I am using Microsoft SharePoint 2013 Search for retrieving results from some lists by ContentType. I have the problem that my Search results "CreatedBy" is always empty! I have looked at the Managed and Crawled Properties and everything seems to be ok.

I am using the managed property `CreatedBy`. It is mapped to `ows_Created_x0020_By`.

Managed Property setting

- Searchable yes
- Queryable yes
- Retrievable yes
- Include Content from all crawled properties yes -> selected mappings: `ows_Created_x0020_By`

Crawled Properties settings of property `ows_Created_x0020_By`

```
Property Name:  ows_Created_x0020_By

Category: SharePoint
Property Set ID: 00130329-0000-0130-c000-000000131346
```

Mappings to managed properties:

CreatedBy(Text)

`Include in full-text index` is checked!

Has anyone an idea whats wrong with this? Is this a bug? Has anyone same empty CreatedBy column?

**Update**

jwpfox's answer is correct but i want to add one more information to it. By default there are lots of crawled properties mapped to the Author property. I need it to get the CreatedBy column information out of custom list items. When i use the built in Author property i get multiple values back. The creator AND the modifier separated by an comma. I have created a new property which is only mapped to the `Office: 4` crawled property and this works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The internal name for `Created By` is `Author` **not** `CreatedBy`.